# Copying from one text file to another using Python

Tags: python, text-files

I would like to copy certain lines of text from one text file to another. In my current script when I search for a string it copies everything afterwards, how can I copy just a certain part of the text? E.g. only copy lines when it has "tests/file/myword" in it?

current code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
f = open('list1.txt')
f1 = open('output.txt', 'a')

doIHaveToCopyTheLine=False

for line in f.readlines():

    if 'tests/file/myword' in line:
        doIHaveToCopyTheLine=True

    if doIHaveToCopyTheLine:
        f1.write(line)

f1.close()
f.close()
```

Comment: The problem with your code: you have to reset the flag on each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The oneliner:

```
open("out1.txt", "w").writelines([l for l in open("in.txt").readlines() if "tests/file/myword" in l])
```

Recommended with `with`:

```
with open("in.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines = [l for l in lines if "ROW" in l]
    with open("out.txt", "w") as f1:
        f1.writelines(lines)
```

Using less memory:

```
with open("in.txt") as f:
    with open("out.txt", "w") as f1:
        for line in f:
            if "ROW" in line:
                f1.write(line)
```

Comment: Thumbs down for me... this code creates a second list before writing. Its not scalable. Neither readlines() nor a list comprehension creating a second list should be used.

Comment: @ATOzTOA, do these codes close the files? Specially in the first code I don't know how to refer to files for closing!

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasi The file will be automatically closed unless there is an exception. Using `with`, the file will be closed even when there are exceptions.

Comment: @ATOzTOA Hi, what is "ROW". What if we remove the if condition with row, and write the file directly?

Answer (score 10):

readlines() reads the entire input file into a list and is not a good performer. Just iterate through the lines in the file. I used 'with' on output.txt so that it is automatically closed when done. That's not needed on 'list1.txt' because it will be closed when the for loop ends.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
with open('output.txt', 'a') as f1:
    for line in open('list1.txt'):
        if 'tests/file/myword' in line:
            f1.write(line)
```

Answer (score 9):

Just a slightly cleaned up way of doing this. This is no more or less performant than ATOzTOA's answer, but there's no reason to do two separate with statements.

```
with open(path_1, 'a') as file_1, open(path_2, 'r') as file_2:
    for line in file_2:
        if 'tests/file/myword' in line:
            file_1.write(line)
```

Answer (score 7):

Safe and memory-saving:

```
with open("out1.txt", "w") as fw, open("in.txt","r") as fr: 
    fw.writelines(l for l in fr if "tests/file/myword" in l)
```

It doesn't create temporary lists (what `readline` and `[]` would do, which is a non-starter if the file is huge), all is done with generator comprehensions, and using `with` blocks ensure that the files are closed on exit.

Answer (score 2):

```
f=open('list1.txt')  
f1=open('output.txt','a')
for x in f.readlines():
    f1.write(x)
f.close()
f1.close()
```

this will work 100% try this once

Answer (score 2):

in `Python 3.10` with parenthesized context managers, you can use multiple context managers in one with block:

```
with (open('list1.txt', 'w') as fout, open('output.txt') as fin):
    fout.write(fin.read())
```

Answer (score -2):

```
f = open('list1.txt')
f1 = open('output.txt', 'a')

# doIHaveToCopyTheLine=False

for line in f.readlines():
    if 'tests/file/myword' in line:
        f1.write(line)

f1.close()
f.close()
```

Now Your code will work. Try This one.