# copy data from one text file to another in real time using python?

Tags: python, file, file-copying

I have a text file on sd card which I am reading through python. I want to copy contents of this file and save in another sd card, and as I make changes to original file it should reflect run time on the copied version in real time

I went through [Copying from one text file to another using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343743/copying-from-one-text-file-to-another-using-python) but this is static implementation(copied file does not change runtime with changes in original file)

My code:

```
import os

with open("/path/to/file.txt", 'r') as f:
 print (f.read())
 #f.flush()


file = open("/path/to/another/file.txt", 'w')
while True:
    file.write( f)
    file.flush()
   # file.close()
```

Comment: What software is changing the original?  Do you control the source code?  The obvious way is to alter that program to operate on both.

Comment: If you don't have access to the source code of the program that is modifying the file you need to have a separate process that watches the original file and copy it to the destination file if changed. Check some solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/182197/3885927

Comment: I am using python to generate random text in orignal one. My aim is to use another python script(as shown above in the question) to see if I can get the random text saved on sd card as it being generated

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to track *any* changes in the original file, from *any* source, then you have a problem with system security.  By definition of the **file** resource, the OS sees them as distinct entities.

The usual way to handle this is with periodic back-ups.  If you require real-time response, then leave a small program running that will detect writes to the original file (ala Tripwire security) and make the changes on demand.

In general, this is not a Python solution; rather it's something to code at the OS level.