# Looking for Simple Python Formula to Combine Two Text Files

Tags: python, file, text, text-files

Beginner Python user here. I'm trying to write a formula that will merge two text files. As in, the first file should have the text of the second simply *added* to it, not replacing anything in either file.

Here's what I have so far:

```
def merge(file1,file2):
    infile = open(file2,'r')
    infile.readline()
    with open('file1','a') as myfile:
        myfile.write('infile')
        myfile.close()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you trying to merge or just copy content from file2=>file1 or file1=file1+file2?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copying from one text file to another using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343743/copying-from-one-text-file-to-another-using-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have the right idea, a way it could be simplified and easier to read would be the following code I found on google, fit to your method.

```py
def merge(file1,file2):
    fin = open(file2, "r")
    data2 = fin.read()
    fin.close()
    fout = open(file1, "a")
    fout.write(data2)
    fout.close()
```

Comment: Seems to be a typo in `fout = open(file1., "a")`

Comment: Thank you. Fixed.